# Oracle: Physically reorganizing rows of a huge table by a different key

Tags: oracle, index, oracle-12c

I have a huge table `RECORD` -- a few billion rows -- which contains data loaded continuously in a lot of batches. I can assign a primary key `RECORD_ID` from sequence, or use natural composite key `BATCH_NUM + RECORD_NUM`, which gives me a nice, unfragmented table where a batch with thousands of records only spans over several physical blocks, which is useful for next batch-aware step of processing.

But later I need to group together rows from arbitrary batches based on another field value, some `RECORD_KEY`. There are hundreds of millions of different `RECORD_KEY`s spread across rows of the table, therefore if I want to pick 10 rows with the same `RECORD_KEY`, it will almost certainly require retrieval of 10 physical blocks. Due to the table size this also cannot easily be cached so it is 10 physical reads (plus overhead on index traversal). This is obviously very slow.

---

**Example:**

Table RECORD

- `RECORD_ID` is primary key from sequence
- `BATCH_NUM` and `RECORD_NUM` are unique constraint (and could be a primary key)
- `RECORD_KEY` is an indexed column

Sample data:

```
| RECORD_ID | BATCH_NUM | RECORD_NUM | RECORD_KEY
|         1 |         1 |          1 |  987654321
|         2 |         1 |          2 |  876543219
|         3 |         1 |          3 |  765432198
|         4 |         2 |          1 |  654321987
|         5 |         2 |          2 |  543219876
...
| 100000006 |   3000003 |          2 |  432198765
| 100000007 |   3000003 |          3 |  876543219
| 100000008 |   3000003 |          4 |  321987654
...
| 200000009 |   6000004 |          3 |  219876543
| 200000010 |   6000004 |          4 |  876543219
| 200000011 |   6000004 |          5 |  198765432
...
```

This SQL command will be fast because it will only have to retrieve one physical block:

```
select RECORD_ID from RECORD where BATCH_NUM = 1
```

This SQL command will be slow because it will have to retrieve three physical blocks -- one for each retrieved row:

```
select RECORD_ID from RECORD where RECORD_KEY = 876543219
```

EDIT:

The above is **just** an example. Typically I would have:

- thousands of rows per BATCH_NUM
- tens of rows per RECORD_KEY
- thousands of rows per lookup, by BATCH_NUM of RECORD_KEY

SQLs look like this, both retrieving around 1000 rows:

```
select RECORD_ID from RECORD where BATCH_NUM = 123456

select RECORD_ID from RECORD where RECORD_KEY in (
  select COLUMN_VALUE from TABLE(batch_num_tbl) -- 100 values
)
```

The execution plans look both reasonable and similar -- using the respective index. However while the BATCH_NUM lookup takes under 1 second to execute, RECORD_KEY lookup takes around 20 seconds.

---

Options which I considered:

- Partitioning: I could do of hash partitioning on `RECORD_KEY`. It would put the records a bit closer to each other, increasing the chance of them being in the same block, and enabling some partition-wise joins. Might help a bit but will not resolve the problem for me.
- Index-organized table: Since it requires primary key, I would have to make primary key `RECORD_KEY + RECORD_ID`. Also the lookup on `BATCH_NUM` would then become slow.
- Re-inserting the rows: A rather ugly solution, where I would regularly select rows ordered by `RECORD_KEY`, delete them and insert append them, effectively putting them next to each other.

Please note I am not any experienced DBA, just a developer stuck with this non-trivial DB problem.

Comment: How slow is "slow" when retrieving 3 physical blocks, and how "fast" you expect it to be? What does the explain plan look like for the query on `RECORD_KEY`?

Comment: @rdfozz I edited the question to answer your comments.

Comment: Do you have any other payload in your table? Given as above, I have the feeling, this is pointless. Do you lookup other things with the given natural or primary key?

Comment: I am with @Grimaldi. There are many assumptions but few facts to analyze. Blaf why don't you try this with few million rows in a test db and see how it pans out and if your theory holds? Once you experiment, you can share results and then there could be even more constructive discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Create an index on `(record_key, record_id)`. This way oracle will most likely use the index only to answer your slow running query. You can add more columns to that index, so that you also get the needed content. Hopefully you don't need all columns.

Be careful about, what impact this index has on your load performance.

Comment: You probably meant (RECORD_KEY, RECORD_ID) -- the slow query is on RECORD_KEY. It would make sense, but in the next step I will need to actually access some data columns from the record (excluded in my example), so this is not suitable for me.

Comment: Fixed that error. Also added, that you can add more columns

Answer (score 0):

If you find that a simple covering index (which will solve all your query performance problems immediately) has an unacceptable impact on INSERT performance, you can introduce an artificial 'clustering' column to the table:

> ```
> create table foo(
>   record_id integer not null constraint u_foo unique
> , record_key integer not null
> , record_id_grp integer not null -- artificial clustering column
> , bar varchar(100) default lpad('A',10,'A')
> , constraint pk_foo primary key(record_id_grp,record_key,record_id)
> , check(record_id_grp=trunc(record_id/10000)) ) organization index;
> ```
>
> ```
> create trigger trg_foo
> before insert on foo
> for each row
> begin
>   :new.record_id_grp := trunc(:new.record_id/10000);
> end;
> /
> ```
>
> ```
> insert into foo(record_id, record_key)
> select level, floor(dbms_random.value(1,1000))
> from dual
> connect by level<=100000;
> ```

> ```
> select /*+ gather_plan_statistics index_ss(foo pk_foo) */ count(*)
> from foo 
> where record_key=10;
> ```
>
> ```
> | COUNT(*) |
> | -------: |
> |      106 |
> ```

> ```
> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null,null,'ALLSTATS LAST'));
> ```
>
> ```
> | PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                     |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
> | SQL_ID  b1za5v8u2ccxj, child number 0                                                 |
> | -------------------------------------                                                 |
> | select /*+ gather_plan_statistics index_ss(foo pk_foo) */ count(*) from               |
> | foo  where record_key=10                                                              |
> |                                                                                       |
> | Plan hash value: 2217311945                                                           |
> |                                                                                       |
> | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | | Id  | Operation        | Name   | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | |
> | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |        |      1 |        |      1 |00:00:00.01 |      21 | |
> | |   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE  |        |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |      21 | |
> | |*  2 |   INDEX SKIP SCAN| PK_FOO |      1 |    100 |    106 |00:00:00.01 |      21 | |
> | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> |                                                                                       |
> | Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                   |
> | ---------------------------------------------------                                   |
> |                                                                                       |
> |    2 - access("RECORD_KEY"=10)                                                        |
> |        filter("RECORD_KEY"=10)                                                        |
> |                                                                                       |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b518225a771fad15670a03c5c056eb26)*

Notice that only 21 blocks are touched even though about 100 rows are returned. The degree of clustering defined by `trunc(record_id/X)` can be tuned to balance the speed of query on RECORD_KEY with the speed of INSERTS — you can try different values for the divisor. You may be lucky and find you can simply use `BATCH_NUM` for clustering instead.

Note that you don't need to use an IOT — you could instead have a covering index leading with `RECORD_ID_GRP,RECORD_KEY` (or `BATCH_NUM,RECORD_KEY`). With billions of rows I am making the assumption that doubling storage size will come with a cost — a single IOT to achieve clustering will be the solution that takes the least space.